# EXCEL VBA - How to use a relative variable range as an absolute range?

Tags: excel, reference, user-defined-functions, countif, vba

I've looked online and have not come across an answer that seems to work in this specific instance.

In VBA, I am creating a formula that will reference a header row and the range beneath it... $B$1:B1.  This will be used in an UDF (user defined function).

The header cell (B1) will be a user defined input, variable "HC" (for header cell).
I want to create the absolute range of HC and call it HCA (absolute HC)

It will go into a VBA formula like this, unless you know of a better way:

```
Public Function Fred(r as Range, HC as Range) as Long
a = application.worksheetfunction.countif(Range(HCA & ":" & HC), r)
```

where "r" is another range.

The user will enter `=Fred(r,HC)` into a cell in an Excel worksheet, then fill down as far as needed.

Anyone know how to make a relative variable into an absolute variable?

The UDF is based on this formula: [Create a unique distinct alphabetically sorted list, extracted from a column in excel](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/04/14/create-a-unique-alphabetically-sorted-list-extracted-from-a-column/)

`=INDEX(List, MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1, List)=0, 1, MAX((COUNTIF(List, "<"&List)+1)*2))*(COUNTIF(List, "<"&List)+1)), COUNTIF(List, "<"&List)+1, 0))`

Comment: In this instance both would be absolute, you are not autofilling you are asking the formula to return one answer so it does not matter.  vba does not do absolute, because you would simply declare it.  It is only when using the actual formula, wether in a `Evaluate()` or setting the formula to a cell where it would matter.

Comment: It's a user defined function.  It will have a range of answers.

Comment: You would change `(Range(HCA & ":" & HC), r)` to `(HC, r)` and then you would call it `=Fred(A1,$B$1:B1)`  The absolute needs to be on the worksheet side not the vba side.  As stated earlier vba does not do absolute.